# How to solve form aligning without tables when I have multiple rows and want to align the left column right and the right column left

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a solution for the following, aspect: I have a table with two columns (cols). The left col contains form labels, the right col contains inputs. In order to have a good UI experience, I want to align these cols next to each other (left col align right | right col align left). Now I try to solve this without tables, because forms are no table data. The big advantage of tables is:

1. table-cols take automatically the space they need, so the left column is automatically as wide as the widest label
2. in multiple rows I have no problem of losing the row

The following picture is showing my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Ehm.png

So is there a solution which follows the following conditions?:

- no Javascript
- left col/div is taking max. the width of the widest label
- no row conflicts like in the picture

Comment: When a table solves your problem, why are you looking for a solution without tables? A collection of interrelated labels and controls is structurally a matrix (array, table), so there isn’t even any dogmatic reason unless you have wrong dogmas. But if you must, replace the table structure by an amorphous collection of `div` and `span` elements and format it as a table using CSS table properties.

Comment: I agree with @JukkaK.Korpela. If a table solves your problem natively why complicate it with possibly more mark up? You could probably achieve the desired result by rendering the same amount of markup with div's etc and override your chosen UI framework by assigning additional cumbersome CSS or you may even be able to achieve this with flexbox. But why seems like a pointless fight. Further, if you are going to use bootstrap why not adhere to the style guides they provide for forms? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example. I have followed what you mentioned in your reference image but you can also change HTML and CSS according to your requirement. Let me know if it works for you or not.

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px; 
  align-self: flex-start; 
}

input,
textarea {
  flex: 2;
  align-self: flex-start; 
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1">Longer Input Label</label>
    <input type="text" id="input1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2">Input Label</label>
    <input type="text" id="input2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textarea1">Short</label>
    <textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can consider using bootstrap since its

- customizable (use the builder on the website to setup colors, fonts and such and click on generate
- easy to implement (import a css file)
- easy to use (thousands of examples are on the website)
- the grid system will make it possible to build tables without actually using a table tag, that can even react responsible to smaller browser screens like tablets and smartphones.

Url: http://getbootstrap.com/

A table could look like this (note that you have 12 cols in bootstraps grid system and you can freely choose the width using div classes col-md-1 until col-md-12. You can add as many cols as you like, it is just important that you do need exceed the range of 12 cols or it will break your div responsively and display the content in the next row but I dont think you need more then 12 cols to build your form so this should be perfect.

First of all its as easy to implement as this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/path/to/your/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

An example matching to your table would be:

```
<div class="row text-right">
    <div class="col-md-4">Label 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Label 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Label 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row text-left">
    <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="t1" value="" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="t2" value="" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-8"><textarea name="t3" placeholder="Enter some text..."></textarea></div>
</div>
```

For another example lets assume you have fired a database-query and the rows are saved in $data you could realize a table simple as that:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">ID</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Name</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Description</div>
</div>
<?php foreach($data as $row) { ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">$row["id"]</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">$row["name"]div>
        <div class="col-md-6">$row["description"]</div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Another note:

If you only setup col-md-x box-sizes for other screen resolutions are automatically guessed by bootstrap. If you want to define it more specifically you can use classes col-lg-x, col-sm-x and col-xs-x classes for a specific setup for smaller screens such as tables and smartphones are using.

Comment: Hi steini, thanks for that answer. I know bootstrap very well and so I guess this is not the solution of my problem because I have to define the width of my columns by using these col-...-...-classes and this is exactly what I don't want. I want that my left div automatically take the space it needs.

Comment: Because sometimes I would need a col-lg-5 and sometimes a col-lg-7, depending on the label. In order to this all label-divs need to have the same width like you can see in the picture I postet in the original post.

Comment: In this case its not possible without JavaScript because you cannot know if the current col needs to be larger then the current one. Wether you need to analyze the content first with PHP and save the col with the largest width and then build your html, depending on this value or you need to use JavaScript when the document is done loading but you said you dont dont want to use JS so this is nearby impossible.

Comment: So am I right if I say: "there is no solution to solve my problem without javascript and without tables. So I can either do a very complicated preprocessing where I only can approximate the width of the column or I have to use tables even I formular-data is not a table data."?

Comment: Ofcourse you can put a form in a table! It might be not 100% W3C conform and makes slightly trouble when having multiple forms in one table But normally you can use a form inside <td> aswell as wrap an entire table with a <form> tag. It is just a problem when you want to have multiple forms in one table then its going to be tricky.